# Azure Devops Projects - Where did they come from? How to remove?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have been reviewing our Azure account and some of the preview features. When I logged in I see about 7 DevOps projects, mostly for old projects that would never have had any kind of intentional DevOps configuration.

When I click into them, the details screen just sits on loading indefinitely.

Being that I did not create these DevOps projects (at least intentionally through the UI), where would they have come from?

In addition, I see no option to remove them, how can DevOps projects be removed without deleting the actual Team Project?

Comment: It will creates new team project for each DevOps project, what's the problem delete the Team project? Is there delete button when open a DevOps project on azure?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, what I am meaning to say is the Team Projects were there a long time before we looked at DevOps projects. No one on the team created these in Azure, only VSTS. There are about 6 of them in Azure DevOps that can not be removed and the dashboards never load.

Comment: To be more specific, the Team Projects existed before the DevOps Projects. The mystery DevOps projects do not load and can not be fixed or deleted (at least through the web ui). How can I remove them since these were never DevOps enabled Team Projects to begin with? I like my Azure looking neat and tidy. These broken entries keep me up at night!